# How to use Route53 SDK to determine if a domain is available

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-sdk

Using the Java AWS SDK, how can one determine if a subdomain is available.  Let's say I have a hosted zone, xyz.com - programatically I would like to generate a custom url, e.g. joe.xyz.cow,  but first however determine if the 'joe' has already been taken.

I thought the Route53 SDK would offer a straightforward process to see if a name is in use for a hosted zone but all I've found is a CheckDNSAvailability method of the beanstalk API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your are looking for is listResourceRecordSets, exposed by [AmazonRoute53Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/)

Comment: Indeed, I used ListResourceRecordSetsRequest()